# SQL - compare columns for matching set

Tags: sql-server

I have the dataset below and need to identify a master record based on latest date, and produce the output as a parent child match records, if a relationship exists as shown in the result.

```
id1 id2  date1     date2
a    b   1-dec-17  2-dec-17
b    c   2-dec-17  30-nov-17
a    e   1-dec-17  15-dec-17
d    e   14-dec-17 15-dec-17
z    y   14-dec-17 15-dec-17
```

Here the output expected is:

```
id1 id2 date1     date2
e   a   15-dec-17 1-dec-17
e   b   15-dec-17 2-dec-17
e   c   15-dec-17 30-nov-17
e   d   15-dec-17 14-dec-17
y   z   15-dec-17 14-dec-17
```

If you look at the source data `e` has the latest date and there is a relationship `a->b->c->d-e`.

Also the `id1` column in the result should be master record.

Comment: I don't see how `date2` is calculated.

Comment: a->b, b->c there fore a->c. same way if a is related to e means e->b and e>c. here c -> b , means c->a, and a-> e which means c->e, there is another record, d->e which means a and c are related to d via e

Answer (score 0):

Below is a code, which produces the result you want, but result is not guaranteed, because you possible can have date duplicates.

`SELECT id1, id2, CAST(date1 as DATETIME) as date1, CAST(date2 as DATETIME) as date2
INTO #tbl_Temp
FROM ( VALUES 
('a','b','1-dec-2017','2-dec-2017'),
('b','c','2-dec-2017','30-nov-2017'),
('a','e','1-dec-2017','15-dec-2017'),
('d','e','14-dec-2017','15-dec-2017') 
) as a (id1, id2, date1, date2)
GO
;WITH tbl as (
    SELECT id1, date1 FROM #tbl_Temp
    UNION 
    SELECT id2, date2 FROM #tbl_Temp
)
SELECT t1.id1, t2.id1 as id2, t1.date1, t2.date1 as date2
FROM tbl as t2
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT TOP 1 id1, date1 FROM tbl 
    WHERE date1 = (SELECT MAX(date1) FROM tbl )
) as t1 
ON t1.id1 != t2.id1`

BTW I'd suggest to redesign the original table. It does not look right.

Comment: thank you @Slava Murygin , original data as you pointed out is in datetime.i have tested this query, by adding a row  ('z','y','14-dec-2017','15-dec-2017'). in this case record "e" do not have any relation with z and y but still it maps to e. Could you suggest how we should handle when there are records with no relationship come in between ? those records should remain as it is.

Comment: What result would you expect then? You can add `and t1.date1 != t2.date1` to the end, but not sure how you want handle "y".

Comment: i want to bring y in the  id1 column because "y" has latest date when compared to z. in this way id1 column will always be a master record after this relationship processing

Comment: Why to `z`? For instance `e` is compared to `b` & `c` despite they are mot related. Why the 'y' can't relate to `abcd`? You have to bring another model, with easier logic.